# What can I do with read-write access with the JVM SNMP feature?

Tags: java, jvm, snmp

I am working with SNMP monitoring for a Java application using the tooling [described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html).

The ACL template has a section on the format that describes the meaning of the `access` and `managers` options:

```
##############################################################
#               Format of the acl group
##############################################################
#
# communities: a list of SNMP community strings to which the
#              access control applies separated by commas.
#
# access: either "read-only" or "read-write".
#
# managers: a list of hosts to be granted the access rights.
#    Each can be expressed as any one of the following:
#    - hostname: hubble
#    - ip v4 and v6 addresses: 123.456.789.12 , fe80::a00:20ff:fe9b:ea82
#    - ip v4 and v6 netmask prefix notation: 123.456.789.0/24, 
#         fe80::a00:20ff:fe9b:ea82/64  
#      see RFC 2373 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt)
#
# An example of two community groups for multiple hosts:
#    acl = {
#     {
#       communities = public, private
#       access = read-only
#       managers = hubble, snowbell, nanak
#     }
#     {
#       communities = jerry
#       access = read-write
#       managers = hubble, telescope
#     }
#    }
```

If I grant a manger `access = read-write` what can that manager actually write or change in the running JVM?

Does write access allow the manager do something like trigger a GC or heapdump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you can do with JVM SNMP write access, however, it is **possible** to invoke GC.

To find everything in JVM that can be modified via SNMP, you can walk through all `Jvm*Meta` classes belonging to [JDK built-in SNMP server](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/a71d26266469/src/share/classes/sun/management/snmp/jvmmib) and look for non-trivial `SnmpValue` setter:

```
    public SnmpValue set(SnmpValue x, long var, Object data)
```

Here is a list of all writable OIDs in JDK 8u121 with the corresponding JMX methods:

- [`ClassLoadingMXBean.setVerbose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ClassLoadingMXBean.html#setVerbose-boolean-)
  (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.1.4)
- [`MemoryMXBean.setVerbose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#setVerbose-boolean-) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.2)
- [`MemoryMXBean.gc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html#gc--) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.3)
- [`MemoryPoolMXBean.setCollectionUsageThreshold`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html#setCollectionUsageThreshold-long-) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.131)
- [`MemoryPoolMXBean.setUsageThreshold`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html#setUsageThreshold-long-) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.110)
- [`MemoryPoolMXBean.resetPeakUsage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html#resetPeakUsage--) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.2.110.1.5)
- [`ThreadMXBean.setThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#setThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled-boolean-) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.5)
- [`ThreadMXBean.setThreadCpuTimeEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#setThreadCpuTimeEnabled-boolean-) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.6)
- [`ThreadMXBean.resetPeakThreadCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#resetPeakThreadCount--) (1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.3.7)